# Create drupal 9 platform in Aegir

Tags: 9, aegir

I need to create a new platofrm for Drupal 9 in Aegir.

I have created a makefile in /var/aegir/platform/makefiles/d9.make.

```ini
api = 2
core = 9.x
projects[] = "drupal"
```

I get the *No release history available for drupal 9.x.* error. It seems there is a release from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x but not from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/9.x.

Comment: Make? Why not Composer?

Comment: The folder structure is different in aegir multisite.